# Unable to use Heroku from the commandline

Tags: facebook, command-line, heroku

Currently I'm making a Facebook app with Heroku, I did as the instruction says, but then I get stuck after installing heroku-toolbelt. I opened cmd.exe, typed something like 'heroku', but it results in an error as follows

> C:/Program Files/Heroku/bin/heroku:15:in `[]': code converter not found (UTF-16LE to Windows-1258) (Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError) 
>   from C:/Program Files/Heroku/bin/heroku:15:in`'

I don't know what is the problem, searching around but there's no luck at all.

Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just typing `heroku` in the command line won't do anything. First go to the directory where you have set up a folder to put all the files of your app from command line using DOS commands. Then type `heroku login`. It'll prompt you for user credentials for your heroku account. Enter those correctly and you're good to go from there.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error as you did. Windows-1258 is text code for Vietnamese language. I figured something like to stop converting text code automatically  to Windows- 1258.

So here is how it works for me. Hope it works for you too. Simply go to Control Panel --> Change keyboards or other input method --> Administrative tab --> Change System Locale (from Vietnamese to English (United States) for example). Restart and work like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I need to dig around some more and find a way to build in this kind of functionality, but as a work around, if you open a new command prompt and type "chcp 1252" prior to running any commands it will switch command.exe to a compatible code page.  That should prevent encoding errors of this type.  Sorry for the inconvenience, but it should at least function as a stop gap and I'll work to integrate a fix into the tool itself.  Thanks!