# How to install Heroku on Windows?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku, interface-builder, facebook-apps

I'm making a Facebook app with Heroku, I did as the instructions from heroku and facebook help pages, but then I got stuck after installing heroku-toolbelt. I opened `cmd.exe`, typed  `heroku` as the instructions tell, but it results in an error as follows

> C:/Program Files/Heroku/bin/heroku:15:in []': code converter not found
>   (UTF-16LE to Windows-1258) (Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError) from
>   C:/Program Files/Heroku/bin/heroku:15:in'

I don't know what is the problem, searching around for 1 whole day but there's no luck at all.
Maybe the reason is I'm only young and know very little....

Does anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

There was another similar question asked on this site itself [Unable to use Heroku from the commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986433/unable-to-use-heroku-from-the-commandline)

But there, the chosen answer said something about going to the directory where the questioner has set up a folder for the app...

I am starting to have a headache...Can anyone please give me instructions step by step (if not, any other way is also ok).

Comment: @hims056 What happens when you type "heroku login"?

Comment: @Neil This question is asked by @[Ivisire](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1561080/ivisire)

Comment: Oops! @Ivisire What happens when you type "heroku login"?

Comment: @Neil It says:'The system cannot find the path specified.'

Comment: @hims056 Thanks for the edit...i was really becoming hopeless..

Comment: It sounds like you haven't downloaded the Heroku Toolbelt properly. You can find details here... https://toolbelt.heroku.com/windows Once this is downloaded and installed correctly you should be able to run "heroku login"

Answer (score 2):

If you use Windows 7, go to Control Panel --> Region and Language --> Administrate --> Change system locale... and change current system locale to English (Untied States).

And restart Windows.

It works fine!